# Scope from array only those objects in which one of the users is current user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a simple ToDo application, where I have Projects, who have many tasks, who have many subtasks. Users can be assigned to projects, tasks and subtasks.

In part of my app(on project show page), I wish to show tasks & subtasks that are overdue. I pick them with following code:

```
 35     @project_tasks = @project.tasks 
 36     @project_subtasks = @project.subtasks
 37   
 38     # OVERDUE
 39     @overdue_tasks = @project_tasks.overdue
 40     @overdue_subtasks = @project_subtasks.overdue
 41     @overdue_tasks_and_subtasks = @overdue_tasks + @overdue_subtasks
 42     @overdue_tasks_and_subtasks_sorted = @overdue_tasks_and_subtasks.sort_by {|object| object.target }
```

This shows overdue tasks and subtasks for all users on some project. However, I wish to have the option when the user clicks on a button, he only sees tasks and subtasks he is assigned to. So the following scope would be appropriate on line 43:

```
@overdue_tasks_and_subtasks_from_current_user_sorted = @overdue_tasks_and_subtasks_sorted.where( #one of the users is the current_user )
```

How to write that scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@overdue_tasks_and_subtasks_sorted` is an array, I suppose you could use Array#select:

```
@overdue_tasks_and_subtasks_from_current_user_sorted = @overdue_tasks_and_subtasks_sorted.select do |task|
 task.users.include?(current_user)
end
```

The exact nature of the selection criteria will naturally depend on how you've associated tasks/subtasks with users, and how you're tracking the current user.

My instinct is that you could make this more efficient with some clever database queries, but exactly how that would work depends on a number fo factors - which database you're using, whether you're on Rails 3 or not, what your models are and how the interact, etc.

Comment: if I could I'd give you 1000 points :) thank you, worked like a charm. I am using MySQL and rails 3. can you help me make more efficient queries with that info?

Comment: @oFca Look into how Rails 3's ActiveRelation works. In general, it'll be faster to do filtering in the database, using `.joins` and `.where`, rather than, for instance, actually loading those objects into memory and using `.select`. Additionally, you can often gain a lot of performance through intelligent use of  eager loading (via the `.includes` method). This guide is probably a good place to start: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: yeah, read that guide before, but couldn't figure out much... If you have time, I'd very much appreciate if you'd write what you thought in code, it would help me a great deal.